# Identifying which part of a large document is being compiled

Tags: pdftex

I've a large document partitioned into several files and glued together with `\input` and `\include`. To improve detecting errors it would be quite helpful if everytime a new file is entered `pdflatex` would write an identification text. Is that possible and how? Thanks

Comment: The `\includeonly` command should help to filter the faulty `\include` ones...

Comment: Solved: It turns out the error was stored in and old *.toc or *.out and it was related to the use of an accented letter inside a \label, even though all my document is utf8. I had noticed the problem before, but using \label{Efusión} was a recent addition. Fran: I've implemented your suggestion. @David Carlisle: I love your suggestion, I'll modify my compile bash to use that!!! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log marks the opening of each file with `(/path/to/file` and the closing of each file by `)` so by matching `()` pairs in the log you can see which file is being read as any any error or message is output.

To avoid matching `()` pairs for error messages you can use (with web2c based tex implementations) the `-file-line-error` commandline option in which error messages are prefixed with `filename:linenumber` instead of the traditional `l.linenumber`

Comment: Your suggestion was included in my compile bash: <code>                     #! /bin/bash
# compile.sh - script to compile the indicated *.tex file.
# Usage: compile.sh input .... wil compile input.tex
in=$1
#echo "${in}"
if [ -f "${in}.tex" ]; then
   texclean
   texfot pdflatex -file-line-error ${in}.tex
   #grep 'LaTeX Warning' ${in}.log
   bibtex ${in}
   texfot pdflatex -file-line-error ${in}.tex
   texfot pdflatex -file-line-error ${in}.tex
else
   echo "${in}.tex NO existe!!!"
   echo "Use: $0 foo to compile foo.tex!"
fi

Answer (score 6):

There are already in your log file some indications as `(./subfile.tex)` when  `\input{subfile}` is loaded, but if you want to see some more explicit in the log file, use `\typeout`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\typeout{--- here come my first subfile ---}
\input{subfile1}
\typeout{--- here come my second subfile ---}
\input{subfile2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked fine! Thanks. I edited my *.tex files to reflect starting and ending with your suggestion.

Comment: @samcarter Thanks. I didn't know that step. I had voted up the useful answers. In fact both suggestions have worked and I'm using them, but I cannot check both.